# how to fetch data from two collections with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i have two collections

```
"plandesigns": [
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("6290e030a3f3e1177751e9ea"),
     "planInfo": {
       "states": [
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("6290e030a3f3e1177751e9ec"),
           "stateId": ObjectId("5c1b5769e347b8652304a9a1"),
         },
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("6290e030a3f3e1177751e9ed"),
           "stateId": ObjectId("5c1b5769e347b8652304a9a3"),
         }
       ]
     },
   }
 ]
```

and

```
"planstates": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5c1b5769e347b8652304a9a1"),
      "displayName": "California",
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5c1b5769e347b8652304a9a3"),
      "displayName": "New Jersey",
    }
  ]
```

basically, i need to fetch the states from plandesigns collection based on states.stateId, however, i need the final result to contain the displayName from states collection.

I tried this

```
db.plandesigns.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "planstates",
      localField: "planInfo.states.stateId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "states",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$states"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": "$states._id",
      "displayName": "$states.displayName",
      
    }
  },
  
])
```

but I don't know how to fetch data from plandesigns using $project, how can I do this? the final result should look like this:

```
{
   // plandesign data,
   "_id": ObjectId("6290e030a3f3e1177751e9ea"),
   "planInfo": {
      "states": [
         {
             "_id": ObjectId("6290e030a3f3e1177751e9ec"),
            "stateId":ObjectId("5c1b5769e347b8652304a9a1"),
             "displayName": "California",
         }
      ]
   },
}
```

Comment: [Are you looking for this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AUjY_t5asr8)

Comment: @Gibbs yes, could you please provide an explanation on that? I'm not sure why I need to unwind states before lookup

Comment: @Gibbs actually I need to keep the plandesigns data as it is, the only that has to be changed is the states property, displayName should be inserted inside states in the final result

Answer (score 0):

```
db.plandesigns.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$planInfo.states" //As it's an array, we need operation on one of array fields, we need to reshape it
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "planstates",
      localField: "planInfo.states.stateId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "states",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$states", //To project the states id, we need this
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      stateId: "$planInfo.states._id",
      displayName: "$states.displayName"
    }
  }
])
```

It's about the simplicity. You can achieve the desired format from your attempt as well but that will result in few more stages which would impact the performance.